# Why pmax(dataFrame, int) would introduce NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I'm running into a behavior of `pmax` that I can't quite understand:

```
pmax(data.frame(matrix(1:16, nrow=4)), c(6))
```

would return

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  6 NA  9 13
2  6  6 10 14
3  6  7 11 15
4  6  8 12 16
```

What I don't understand is why only the entries smaller than 6 and are not in the first column got turned into `NA` - if we recycle `c(6, NA, NA, NA)` through the rows, wouldn't all of `X2`, `X3`, `X4` be `NA` since `max(NA, anything) = NA`? Why only the entries that are not in the first column and is smaller than 6 is changed into `NA`s?

Comment: That is not how `pmax` is used. Example: `do.call(pmax,data.frame(matrix(1:16, nrow=4)))`. Or `pmax(df[[1]],df[[2]])`.  It takes a sequence of arguments.

Comment: or `dd <- data.frame(matrix(1:16, nrow=4)); dd[] <- lapply(dd, pmax, 6); dd`

Comment: @Frank: Thanks! But isn't `data.frame(matrix(1:16, nrow=4)), c(6)` also a sequence albeit with difference sizes? The documentation says the shorter input will get recycled, and that is also why am I not understanding the situation.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei recycled as in `pmax(1:4, 3)`, the 3 is being recycled. `pmax` just doesn't have a method for data frames

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion; rawr answered that now, I think. While data.frames shouldn't work as args to `pmax` (only vectors do), you can iterate over column vectors of a data.frame with `lapply` (rawr's example) or pass them all to a single `pmax` call with `do.call` (my comment). It wasn't clear to me which you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Frank and rawr (when can SO support multiple @s?)! So this code has undefined behavior and can do whatever it feels like doing?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes :) You could dissect it to figure out what it's doing, I suppose; might be a good way of learning R's intricacies

Comment: Not undefined, but I guess not very well-defined either. Think of it as basically meant for application to vectors of the same size. Its authors realized that, at very little cost in coding, it could be extended to work nicely for matrices and arrays, which are 'just' vectors with a few additional attributes. As a by-product, it also *happens* to work for all-numeric data.frames that are the same size. But I wouldn't recommend relying on it for anything beyond vectors (and matrices/arrays). Here, you could just do:  `df[df<6] <- 6`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pmax` is not designed to be used with data.frame input.

The error is introduced in line 35 of `pmax`:

```
mmm[change] <- each[change]
```

because `each` is defined to be as long as the `length` of the input, which for a data.frame is the number of columns. Therefore when it tries to address the 5th element, it gets NA.

```
each
[1] 6 6 6 6
each[change]
[1]  6  6  6  6 NA
```

The obvious workaround is to convert to data.frame after using `pmax`:

```
data.frame(pmax(matrix(1:16, nrow=4), c(6)))
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  6  6  9 13
2  6  6 10 14
3  6  7 11 15
4  6  8 12 16
```

Or convert back and forth as required.